# ts-node: importing a JS file that uses import and export

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, ts-node

I'm trying to get this script running using the `ts-node` command:

```
// my-script.ts
import SearchIntegrator from "search-integrator/src/main/search-integrator"
console.log(SearchIntegrator)
```

But it seems that the SearchIntegrator NPM package is using `import` statements internally:

```
// search-integrator.js
import Parser from "./backend/parser/parser.js";
// …
```

…which is causing this error:

```
$ ts-node my-script.ts
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /node_modules/search-integrator/src/main/search-integrator.js from my-script.ts not supported.
```

I've spent the last couple of hours trying out all sorts of config option combinations I've found online. For example:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

…or

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    }
  }
}
```

…or even `"moduleResolution": "node"`.

However, the only thing it affected were the error messages, like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6`.

The more options I've tried the less I understood. I'm really only trying to `import` that NPM module on which I have no impact code-wise.

I'm also open for other tools if `ts-node` isn't the way to go.

I'm using the latest LTS Node (v18) and the latest version of ts-node (v10).

Comment: It seems to work correctly if I add "type": "module", in my package.json. Does that work for you ?

Comment: It says `ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope at file:///Users/me/my-script.ts:2:23`

Comment: You should not use exports in your my-script.ts and use the standard import export ? Or is it in another file you don't control ?

Comment: I'm not using any exports in `my-script.ts` and there are no other files. It's exactly as depicted in my post. Also, I removed `tsconfig.json` to make sure it's as clean as possible. I'm running it using `npx ts-node --esm my-script.ts`.

Comment: (Btw. I don't understand the connection between TypeScript and `package.json` – AFAIK TypeScript is a compiler that translates TypeScript into JavaScript – I wouldn't know why it should depend on `package.json` which describes a package within the NPM ecosystem – something completely unrelated to a compiler. But of course I can be wrong).

Comment: @kraftwer1 You'll probably need to tell both tsc to keep ESM module format during transpilation and nodejs to run the file as ESM

Comment: @Bergi I was hoping `--esm` would do that.

Comment: @kraftwer1 Apparently it doesn't, that's only for the loader? I don't know, but I found https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/module-type-overrides, which states: "*When deciding how a file should be compiled and executed - as either CommonJS or native ECMAScript module - `ts-node` matches `node` and `tsc` behavior. This means TypeScript files are transformed according to your* tsconfig.json *`"module"` option and executed according to node's rules for the* package.json *`"type"` field. Set `"module": "NodeNext"` and everything should work.*"

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I had to 1) rename my file to `.mts` which confuses me – why this hard dependency on a file name? What if I want to call my file `foobar`? I guess I'd wished some CLI option for this, like `ts-node --input-type="module" foobar`. I know that I could also use the `"type"` field in my `package.json`, but again, what if I don't have a `package.json` at all? And 2) altering the command. It works now, see my answer. Thanks again for helping me. If you want, you can also add an answer and I'll accept that. After all, it was your solution.

Comment: It's not a "hard dependency", it's just how the default is chosen if you don't have a *package.json*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity reasons I've deleted both `tsconfig.json` and `package.json` and got it working by renaming `my-script.ts` to `my-script.mts` and running it using this command:

```
ts-node --esm --compilerOptions '{ "module": "esnext" }' my-script.mts
```